# Cloud DataFlow SQL from BigQuery UI cannot read Cloud Storage filesets: "Table not found: datacatalog.entry"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a Data Flow job using the beta Cloud DataFlow SQL within Google Big Query UI.
My data source is a Cloud Storage Fileset (that is a set of files in Cloud Storage defined through a Data Catalog).
Following [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/data-sources-destinations), I was able to define my fileset, assign it a schema and visualize it in the *Resources* tab of Big Query UI.
But then I cannot launch any Dataflow job in the Query Editor, because I get the following error message in the query validator: **Table not found: datacatalog.entry.*location.entry_group.fileset_name..***.

Is it an issue of some APIs not authorized?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look at [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/sql/data-sources-destinations#using-gcs-fileset) in order to validate again your fileset full path in a particular query.

Comment: Thanks but clicking on "Query fileset" in the Details Panel,  BQ automatically fills the Query editor with a fully-qualified, dot-separated list of identifiers that follow the Standard SQL lexical structure. So this does not seem to me the issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same, created the fileset, can add it from the 'Add Data' menu, see the schema, click the "Query Fileset" and it says table not found.
I note that the documentation does say it only supports CSV files without Headers (which needs a switch to ignore) I wonder if the data doesn't match the schema and format requirements?

Answer (score 0):

You may be using the wrong location in the full path. When your create a Data Catalog Fileset, check the location you provided, i.e: using the `sales regions` example from the docs:

```
gcloud data-catalog entries create us_state_salesregions \
--location=us-central1 \
--entry-group=dataflow_sql_dataset \
--type=FILESET \
--gcs-file-patterns=gs://us_state_salesregions_{my_project}/*.csv \
--schema-from-file=schema_file.json \
--description="US State Sales regions..."
```

When you are building your DataFlow SQL query:

```
SELECT tr.*, sr.sales_region
FROM pubsub.topic.`project-id`.transactions as tr
  INNER JOIN    
datacatalog.entry.`project-id`.`us-central1`.dataflow_sql_dataset.us_state_salesregions AS sr
  ON tr.state = sr.state_code
```

Check the full path, it should look like the example above:

datacatalog.entry, then your location - in this example is **us-central1**, next your **project-id**, next your entry group id - in this example **dataflow_sql_dataset**, next your entry id - in this example **us_state_salesregions**

let me know if this works for you.